# Laravel, eloquent, pivot, different table for different kind of data

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, pivot-table

I am going crazy...

I have:
- a Test model and a tests table (Id,name,some other fields)
- a Module model and a modules table (Id,name,some other fields different from Test), for module I mean a portion of a course, a long text;
- a Course model and a courses table (Id,name,some other fields)
- a pivot table courses_module and a related CourseModule Model for the pivot table

The purpose is: I have many tests and many modules that combined together result in courses. I know I could make a (manually managed) pivot table like: Id, course_id, module_id, test_id, assuming that ONLY one field between module_id and test_id can be filled on every single row and checking which one is compiled between these two I can find out what's next in this course (a module or a test).

Or, another manually solution is a pivot like this: Id, course_id, next_section_id (can be id of module of id of test), next_section_type (a string that can be "module" or "test") and I have to make a check on each row to find out if the next_section_id is referring to a test or a module.

Or third bad solution: I do not split tests and modules in two different table (as it shoul!) but create a large table with all the columns I need, at this point I can use eloquent because is a classic pivot table structure between this bad table and courses table, but for each row I have to check (looking at the empty fields) if I have a test or a module...really bad idea against any SQL normalisation rule.

I would like to use a correct way and in the mean time no loose eloquent, if there is a way...it is a logical problem, because a course is a big sequence of two different kind of object, modules and tests...

If it is not clear imagine a easier example, houses table, dogs table, humans table, a pivot table to store all the living inside a house; inside a house maybe we have only humans, sometimes only dogs, sometime humans and dogs...and the pivot in eloquent links only two tables, not three or more.

Comment: Not sure it's what you need exactly, but you might take a look at polymorphic relationships http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

Comment: Thanks! Let's have a look, it should be what I was looking for, an eloquent way to accomplish my second solution which thought it was bad.